# using jquery UI autocomplete with external Json

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, jquery-ui

How can I use jquery UI autocomplete widget with https://www.w3schools.com/js/customers_mysql.php
for example

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answer here: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

But it basically says that you do something like:

```
$( function() { 
    $( "#id" ).autocomplete({
        source: "https://www.w3schools.com/js/customers_mysql.php",
        minLength: 2
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you able to show how you've done it using jsfiddle so that I can assist you further?